# WPF: Eliminate transparency between grid cells

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a Grid in WPF. The Grid has a transparent background (necessary) and each of the cells potentially has a different colored solid background, or maybe no background. When I put arbitrary content in these cells, when two adjacent cells both have colored backgrounds (same or different color, it doesn't matter) there is often (and unpredictably) a thin transparent line separating them, allowing you to see through the grid at that line.

Does anyone know how this could possibly be fixed?

Edit: Meant to mention it in my question, but I've tried enabling SnapsToDevicePixels anywhere and everywhere I can, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any code my guess is that you need [SnapsToDevicePixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels.aspx) on the elements in the grid.

Comment: Meant to mention it in my question, but I've tried enabling SnapsToDevicePixels anywhere and everywhere I can, to no avail.

Comment: Ugh, I tried to write a sample but it doesn't capture the problem so I'll have to try to get more out from the "real" application to write a sample.

Comment: Can you pin it down to particular cell content?  Does forcing a redraw (minimise etc) remove the issue?  Is it possible you accidentally have an empty column/row at that point?

Comment: I see the problem when one of the cells has content that varies. This is in a subclassed Window, and you can set the Content of one specific cell. Different sizes of Content (which stretch the cell and window) cause different lines to appear.

Comment: Appears when going bigger, or only when going smaller?

Comment: Ooh, I have a sample that can reproduce what I think is the same issue.  Will post it in a new answer in a few ticks.

Answer (score 1):

This produces the same issue, but it may not be the same exact cause.  Still, if we can resolve this it might give a hint for your issue.

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="PaleGoldenrod" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="White" />
        <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="PaleGoldenrod" />


        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" />
        <!-- This is in the significant cell -->
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SizeChangeLabel" Background="PaleGoldenrod">
            Watch this cell
        </Label>
        <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" />

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Background="PaleGoldenrod" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Background="White" />
        <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Background="PaleGoldenrod" />


        <Button x:Name="ReduceContentSize" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Click="ReduceContentSize_Click">Reduce</Button>
        <Button x:Name="IncreaseContentSize" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"   Click="IncreaseContentSize_Click">Increase</Button>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="White">
            The window is black
        </TextBlock> 
</Grid>
```

The click events adjust the MinWidth of the label in the centre cell.  When you bump it up, you get lines which I assume are the same as your issue.

```
private const double _sizeChangeAmount = 150;

    private void IncreaseContentSize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SizeChangeLabel.MinWidth = SizeChangeLabel.ActualWidth + _sizeChangeAmount;
        SizeChangeLabel.MinHeight = SizeChangeLabel.ActualHeight + _sizeChangeAmount;   
    }

    private void ReduceContentSize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SizeChangeLabel.MinWidth > 150)
            SizeChangeLabel.MinWidth = SizeChangeLabel.ActualWidth - _sizeChangeAmount;

        if (SizeChangeLabel.MinHeight > 150)
            SizeChangeLabel.MinHeight = SizeChangeLabel.ActualHeight - _sizeChangeAmount;
    }
```

Is this a reasonable approximation that can help lead to a solution?

Comment: That's very similar to an approximation I tried, but this problem is solved via adding SnapsToDevicePixels=true on all of the elements (not sure where exactly it's necessary, so I put it on everything even though I think it trickles down.) I swear I have the problem even with SnapsToDevicePixels on.

Comment: Interesting-- I put SnapsToDevicePixels on the window, the grid, all the labels, the buttons and the TextBlock, and I still get those lines.  What size-related properties are you using on the window?  (SizeToContent etc).

Comment: You could hack it by making the margins on the content -1.  But I hate that.  :(

Comment: The window is SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight". I'll try the Margins technique just for the hell of it.