# WPF UC in Winforms occasionally has an odd border to the left / visually corrupted

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, user-controls

I have a WPF user control I created that is used to show the state of tasks in my UI. I get the odd report back that the control sometimes has a nasty looking border to the left and I cannot reproduce it.

The control looks like this (when working) (grey tick=not run, green=OK,red cross=fail,hourglass=running);

[alt text http://img504.imageshack.us/img504/1772/wpfgoodpw9.png](http://img504.imageshack.us/img504/1772/wpfgoodpw9.png)

It looks like this when the problem occurs;

[alt text http://img369.imageshack.us/img369/4201/wpfbadar6.png](http://img369.imageshack.us/img369/4201/wpfbadar6.png)

It may have something to do with the layering of those icons, when the state changes the others are made invisible and the relevant icon is made visible. The four icons are all stacked on top of each other.

It could also be the background in theory, which I'll look at next. Problem is reported on both flat panel and CRT displays.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Update:
1) SnapsToDevicePixels does not affect the issue.
2) Grid is not used, only a canvas.

Comment: It's the pixel snapping as mentioned below by Cameron.

Answer (score 1):

Could it have something to do with [pixel snapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908.aspx)?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not it, but it sounded likely. Good background though, I was not aware of pixel snapping.

Answer (score 0):

Are they in a grid?  It could be related to [WPF: Eliminate transparency between grid cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267364/wpf-eliminate-transparency-between-grid-cells#267954) which we never really resolved.

Comment: No grid in use, just a canvas. But they seem linked somehow. I'll have to make it simpler I think with blocks of colour and see if I can get a sample up to reproduce it. Could be linked to DPI somehow though as only happens on certain systems (not mine obviously).

Answer (score 0):

You could ask one of your tech-savvy users to run [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) while the problem is showing, then:

1. Click on the binoculars
2. Put the mouse over the artifact (vertical bar) and press Shift-Ctrl
3. Look in the Snoop window and tell you which item is hilighted

This will tell you exactly what control is producing the color you are seeing in the artifact, which may be a big clue in fixing it.